# I want to change what counts as "modifying" a library item

Tags: library

I do not want the items in my library to be considered "modified" if I am simply updating properties. I would only want it to count as modified if the actual file is changed. I sort my libraries by "modified" and when I'm mass updating properties it kinda messes everything up.

This seems like a fairly reasonable request, but who knows.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible through out of box methods;  the behavior is hard wired.

Speculation:  You probably could get behavior like what you describe by creating a date & time column in the library and using a custom coded Event Receiver to update the date/time in that column when a file is changed.